# Detect TCP Connection Disconnection

Tags: go, tcpclient

Problem : Client need to create tcp connection, and reconnect if for some reason connection drops, also it can be asked to disconnect anytime.

Server is not in my hands, no data is sent on the connection, only connection establishment is required.

My implementation using TCP keep alive, I followed https://thenotexpert.com/golang-tcp-keepalive/

```
func (s *State) spawnCtrlConnection() (quit chan struct{}) {
    quit = make(chan struct{}, 1)

    go func(addr string) {

        tcpAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", s.addr())
        if err != nil {
            s.HandleError(err)
            return
        }

        conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, tcpAddr)
        if err != nil {
            s.HandleError(err)
            return
        }

        defer func() {
            conn.Close()
        }()

        conn.SetKeepAlive(true)
        conn.SetKeepAlivePeriod(time.Second * time.Duration(s.WaitInterval))

        rawConn, err := conn.SyscallConn()
        if err != nil {
            s.HandleError(err)
            return
        }

        rawConn.Control(
            func(fdPtr uintptr) {
                fd := int(fdPtr)

                // Ping amount
                err = syscall.SetsockoptInt(fd, syscall.IPPROTO_TCP, syscall.TCP_KEEPCNT, s.PingAmount)
                if err != nil {
                    s.HandleError(err)
                    return
                }
                // Retry interval
                err = syscall.SetsockoptInt(fd, syscall.IPPROTO_TCP, syscall.TCP_KEEPINTVL, s.RetryInterval)
                if err != nil {
                    s.HandleError(err)
                    return
                }
            })

        for {
            select {
            case <-quit:
                return
            default:

                data := make([]byte, 1)
                _, err = conn.Read(data)
                // it blocks here forever and (<- quit will never receive anything)

                // setting explicit timeout doesn't help either, as it will timeout for obvious reason
                //  conn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second * time.Duration(s.WaitInterval)))

                //  if err != nil {
                //      if err, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && err.Timeout() {
                //          fmt.Println("timeout", err.Error())
                //      } else {
                //          fmt.Println("I am here", err.Error())
                //      }
                //  }

                // WHAT SHOULD I CODE


            }
        }
    }()
    return
}
```

I don't understand, what should I code that detect disconnection.

May be I misunderstood the concept of tcp keep-alive.

Please help.

Comment: just use a `for` ever loop which connects at beginning. Let Read block and timeout, adjust them, when it returns a connection lost error, just return at the beginning of the loop. You can also add a flag to detect first run, thus determine it reconnects. If the server sends a quit command, unclear, simply break out the loop.

Comment: in any cases, you cannot quit until read has returned.

Comment: reading blocks for timeout period and I won't be able to disconnect in that time interval

Comment: how nc detects, is timeout is very low in case of netcat command ?

Comment: I set connection time out to 1 second, so that every second there is an opportunity to quit, but still I will be available to know only after WaitInterval + PingAmount * RetryInterval , Can't I know as soon as it disconnects

Comment: There is no such thing as a "disconnect" message in TCP. You read from a connection until it is closed. That's all there is.

Comment: Setup keep alive using [SetKeepAlive](https://godoc.org/net#TCPConn.SetKeepAlive) and [SetKeepAlivePeriod](https://godoc.org/net#TCPConn.SetKeepAlivePeriod).  Read the connection until read returns an error.  That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggested code.

The `for !done` loop is to reconnect when the connection has been closed as long as quit wasn’t closed.

The `for conn != nil` loop is to execute the select repeatedly.

The `SetDeadLine` is put before the `Read`. We do get a Timeout() error when the dead line kicks in. Note that I beleive that we may also get a timeout when the keep alive fails.

```golang
func (s *State) spawnCtrlConnection() (quit chan struct{}) {
    quit = make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        var done bool
        for !done {

            // ... open connection ...

            for conn != nil {
                var buf [1]byte
                select {
                case <-quit:
                    conn.Close()
                    conn = nil
                    done = true
                    continue
                default:
                    conn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Duration(s.WaitInterval)*time.Second))
                    _, err = conn.Read(buf[:])
                    if err != nil {
                        if err == io.EOF {
                            conn.Close()
                            conn = nil
                            continue
                        }
                        if err, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && err.Timeout() {
                            continue
                        } else {
                            fmt.Println("I am here", err.Error())
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }()

    return quit
}
```